# views exposed form alter hook works with login but not work with out login?

Tags: views

I have created views exposed form for searching title based content and i want to display search results into another page for this i have wrote below code in my custom module,it's working fine with login but can't work with out login please advice.

```
<?php
function module_name_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 drupal_set_message('Form Hook Called');//just to check that hook is called by drupal
  if($form['#id'] == 'form id here')
  {

    $form['#action'] = base_path().'path';
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: can you add permission on views ??

Comment: where can i add permissions i mean permissions for views module? currently my views module have permission to administrator

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `code` on `search_redirect_permission`.You have to use

`access search_redirect module content` in `user_access` function to display result.You have to use `search` api under anonymus login codition.

**Something like:**

```
if (user_access('access search_redirect module content')) {
  // search results!
 } else {
  // no search results!
 }
```

But I don't understand why you are using `hook_permission()`,if it should be viewed by anonymous users.

**EDIT:** For `form redirect` you should do something like:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{

    if($form_id == 'your_form_id')
    {
      //YOUR SOME LOGIC IF ANY
      $form['#submit'] = array('custom_form_submit_handler');
    }
}


function custom_form_submit_handler($form, $form_state)
{
//YOUR SOME LOGIC IF ANY
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'your_url';
}
```

Comment: just i have added that hook_permission() for admin side permission option purpose only but i have removed that hook also ,i need to display results in another page but currently display with in the page only ("search_redirect_form_views_exposed_form_alter" this hook working but problem in with out login) i.e i created in views section(productitems),please advice is there any alternate@Hiranya

Comment: what is the reason for displaying views result in other page? and same exposed form will be there too? Also which drupal `version` you are using?

Comment: Issue fixed i have changed Access permissions in views page creation section now it's working fine make sure need above hook for redirection to specific page.Thanks all

Comment: Yes your edit is right if happen any permission issues make sure need to check in created views page.